# Android communication between fragment and baseadapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, baseadapter

Need expert opinion how should i structure this issue. I have a custom method **process_filter** that resides in a fragment as it needs to access a private `TextView` and `List` of this fragment.

In the middle of processing, this fragment will access a `BaseAdapter` and inside this `BaseAdapter` I need to use back **process_filter** method

Basically here is the structure:

**MyFragment.java**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

   private List<String> filter_list;
   private TextView no_of_filter;

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout, container, false);
   no_of_filter = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.no_of_filter_tv);
   .
   MyAdapter custom_adapter = new MyAdapter(context, "string 1", "string 2");
   .
   process_filter("string 1", "string 2");
   .
   }

   public void process_filter(String in_preference, String current_value)
   {
       no_of_filter.setText(in_preference);
   }
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
   class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

       public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup   parent)
       {
             holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Here I need to access back process_filter from fragment 
                    process_filter ("string 1, string 2");
                }
             }
       }
   }
```

Comment: does my suggestion not help you? It's the way communication between adapter and fragment should be done.

Comment: @Marko Yes, I've implemented it and its working. I'm not very familiar with Java Object Oriented Programming but if there is a better way to do this, I would welcome StackOverflow community to leave alternate additional answer. For the spirit of Computer Science :)

Comment: As far as I know, using interfaces is the right way to do it. Another option would be to make a static method in your Fragment, but that is bad, really bad.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create an interface from your adapter to your fragment.

In your adapter create the interface and pass it in your adapter's constructor

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public interface IProcessFilter {
        void onProcessFilter(String string1, String string2)
    }

    private IProcessFilter mCallback;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, String string1, String string2, IProcessFilter callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup   parent)
    {
        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCallback.onProcessFilter("string1", "string2");
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Last thing, implement it in your fragment like this

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements IProcessFilter {
    ...
    ...
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout, container, false);
        no_of_filter = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.no_of_filter_tv);

        MyAdapter custom_adapter = new MyAdapter(context, "string 1", "string 2", this);  
    }

    @Override
    public void onProcessFilter(String string1, String string2) {
        // Process the filter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry For late answer, It may useful for newbies**

**Note:** @Marko answer was perfect but it required a small change  while initializing adapter with parameters.

**Step 1:** Create an listener interface.

```
Public interface AdapterListener{
Public void myListener();
}
```

**Step 2:** Implement your interface in Fragment class.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterListener{

@Override
public void myListener(){
//Do what you want
}
```

**Step 3:** Initializing Adapter class inside `MyFragment` class .

```
MyFragmentAdapter myfragmentAdapter=new MyFragmentAdapter(MyFragment.this);
```

**Step 4:** Initialize your listener in adapter class.

```
 public class MyFragmentAdapter extends Adapter<Your Code Related>{
    private AdapterListener adapterListener;

    public MyFragmentAdapter(AdapterListener adapterListener){
    this.adapterListener=adapterListener;
}
```

Comment: What is `Class`?

Comment: It is class not Class and interface not Interface. Just a type mistake avoid it.