# Communication between BaseAdapter and Fragment

Tags: java, android

First, I know this has been answered here : [Android communication between fragment and baseadapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880248/android-communication-between-fragment-and-baseadapter) and I tried implementing it, but as it is my first time using interfaces and do not get the logic behind it, it did not work. My problem is I would like to set the value of the TextView of this fragment

**Fragment.java**

```
public class FragmentCart extends Fragment {
    private TextView totalTxt;
    private TextView totalItems;
    private ListView itemList;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cart, container, false);
        totalTxt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.totalTxt);
        totalItems = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.totalItems);
        itemList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemList);
        itemList.setAdapter(MainActivity.cart);
        return view;
    }
}
```

with the value (double totalCost) from this adapter

**Adapter.java**

```
public class Cart extends BaseAdapter {
    private double totalCost = 0;

    public getView() {
        Item item.....
        totalCost += item.getPrice();
    }
}
```

The logic is that, as I add items to the cart (adapter) the TextView from the fragment updates as well. How do I do this with interface?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly :

In **Adapter.java** declare a new interface that we'll call `TotalCostUpdater`:

```
public interface TotalCostUpdater {
    void onTotalCostUpdated(int totalCost);
}
```

Then, still in your adapter, you need a field implementing this interface, initialised through a constructor. From there you can call `onTotalCostUpdated(totalCost)` after you updated the value.

Your **Adapter.java** class will then look like this :

```
public class Cart extends BaseAdapter 
{

    public interface TotalCostUpdater {
        void onTotalCostUpdated(int totalCost);
    }

    private double totalCost = 0;

    private TotalCostUpdater costUpdater;

    public Cart(TotalCostUpdater costUpdater) {
        this.costUpdater = costUpdater;
    }

    public getView() 
    {
        Item item.....
        totalCost += item.getPrice();
        costUpdater.onTotalCostUpdated(totalCost);
    }
}
```

You then need to implement `TotalCostUpdater`, and override its `onTotalCostUpdated` method in **FragmentCart.java** :

```
public class FragmentCart extends Fragment implements Cart.TotalCostUpdater 
{
    private TextView totalTxt;
    private TextView totalItems;
    private ListView itemList;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cart, container, false);
        totalTxt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.totalTxt);
        totalItems = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.totalItems);
        itemList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemList);
        itemList.setAdapter(MainActivity.cart);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTotalCostUpdated(int totalCost) {
        totalTxt.setText(totalCost);
    }
}
```

When instantiating your adapter (at some point your must have written a `new Cart()`), you need to pass in your `FragmentCart`, which is now implementing the interface expected in your `Cart`'s constructor :

```
new Cart(fragmentCart);
```

This should do the trick. Here are a few other things you should consider :

- The adapter should **not** be the one holding the data, you should rather have a `CartData` class holding the actual cart values.
- The adapter seems to be global from your `MainActivity.cart`. You should instantiate it directly within the Fragment class
- You should use [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) lib to get rid of all those `findViewById`calls.