# communication between viewpager adapter and viewModel

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I used `recyclerview` inside `viewpager`. Now I want to change the view of my `fragment` when I scroll the recycler view.
I am using `mvvm` and `liveData` and I want to use `viewModel` and send the scroll data to my `viewModel` and in `view` I `observe` the `viewModel` data that comes from `viewPager` adapter.
How can I send the data from `viewPager` adapter and use them in its `fragment`?

```
val linearLayoutManager =
        LinearLayoutManager(container.context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    recCafeList = binding.recCafeList

    recCafeList.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
    recCafeList.adapter = mAdapter



    recCafeList.setOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

            val po = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
            val po2 = linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
            
            // I want to send @po and @po2 to viewModel and use them in fragment
            
            Log.i("scrollListener", "$po //// $po2")
        }

    })

    container.addView(binding.root)

    return binding.root
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom Listener. Create it inside the fragment and transfer it to pagers adapter. And in any time you can call listeners method. Like that - [Android communication between fragment and baseadapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880248/android-communication-between-fragment-and-baseadapter)

It is easy and nice practice solution.

Comment: The question is about ViewPager, not ListView.

Comment: Its no difference at all, bro. Solution is absolutely the same for ListView, RecyclerView, ViewPager, and any other view, that uses an adapter.

Comment: No, FragmentPagerAdapter behaves differently, therefore the solution is a bit different.

Comment: Argue, whats the difference? Youe creating the listener in the fragment, provide it in Adapter, in adapter in the any place you calling the listeners method.

Comment: "Provide it in the adapter"? That will not work after process death.

Comment: What are you talking about? Listener will work while fregment is alive!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230711/discussion-between-yegorf-and-epicpandaforce).

Comment: `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()` is used to create the Fragment if it is not yet added. Once it is added, the FragmentManager will recreate it, and it will have nothing to do do with the FragmentPagerAdapter.